# What is the deference bewteen zeromq binding with * and 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

As title, here is 2 ways to binding a zeromq socket.

```
socket.bind("tcp://*:port")
socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:port")
```

Both these two way work for me, but I am still curious about it.

Comment: does the response answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the server binds to an endpoint and the client connects to an endpoint as follows:

```
# Server
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")
```

connect the socket:

```
# Client
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")
```

By binding to `127.0.0.1` you restrict requests to the server to `127.0.0.1` only. Running locally will work just fine. But when you use different machines with different IPs you will notice the effect. Hence the use of `"*"`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to sitWolf's answer, note that you can bind a socket multiple times, to multiple protocols. For instance:

```
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ);
socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555"); // Bind to localhost
socket.bind("ipc:///tmp/mypipe"); // Also bind to a local pipe
socket.bind("tcp://192.168.0.2:4444"); // Also bind to a specific NIC
```

Also, the socket type is independent of whether you bind it or connect it, though for some socket types it's natural to bind, and others it's natural to connect. So, a PUB socket makes most sense if it's bound, and the corresponding SUB socket connects. Other sockets, one can choose as suits circumstances (e.g. if there is a machine that is more obviously in a server role, that'd be the one to bind).